# Oauth for PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, oauth, pear, dropbox

I am unable to use the Dropbox PHP API (http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/) because of the following error. I tried installing the OAuth extension by downloading a pre-compiled dll and placing it in the ext directory and also tried installing the PEAR library alternative but this just does not work and shows the below error. I even enabled the oauth extension in php.ini but it simply throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox_Exception' with message 'The OAuth class could not be found! Did you install and enable the oauth extension?' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\assets\php\dropbox.php(11): Dropbox_OAuth_PHP->__construct('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php on line 36
```

I am using XAMPP 1.7.3 on windows.

Comment: Have you or haven't you installed the OAuth extension?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `.php` file with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Open it in your web browser from your web server. Is OAuth listed there as installed extension?

If not (which I assume), then you forgot to load the extension in your `php.ini` file.

Open the `php.ini` file (location is also visible in the `phpinfo()` output) and add

```
extension=oauth.dll
```

to it. Restart your webserver then.

Comment: I have tried that.. After googling up for a while.. I came to know many others are also facing this problem. I switched to ubuntu and it works perfectly over there. It seems there is some problem with Windows as the dll is compiled from some other computer, windows is not able to load it. The phpinfo page doesn't list the Oauth extension.